# Symfony2 - Using the Entities database ID for Form Collections array key

Tags: php, symfony

I am building a form collection and it output's the rows like this:

```
<input type="number" name="order[items][1][qty]">
<input type="number" name="order[items][2][qty]">
```

But what I want to do is have this bit:

```
<input type="number" name="order[items][DB_ID_1][qty]">
<input type="number" name="order[items][DB_ID_2][qty]">
```

DB_ID_1 would be a numeric value of the database record ID. So I can print out each row in my template like this:

```
{{ form.items.1 }}
```

So it prints the form element out for the database record with ID 1, currently it prints out the element for the key of 1 which could have the real database id of 9 for example

Any more information required please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I think I understand what you want to do. My question is: Why?

Comment: I want to go through a list of order items and print out the matching qty field input using something like {{ form.items.DB_ID }} - if there is a better method available I am open to suggestions - I am formatting it all inside a table, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found the answer with the help of this post [Embedding a collection of forms Symfony2 forms with adding and deleting allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273272/embedding-a-collection-of-forms-symfony2-forms-with-adding-and-deleting-allowed)

It was such a simple solution - I was looking in the wrong place, I needed to use INDEX BY x.id in my custom Class Repository like so:

```
$em->createQuery("SELECT f FROM ExampleCoreBundle:Folder f INDEX BY f.id WHERE f.uid = :uid");
```

This returned my array of Folder objects back with the keys of the array being the database record's id field for the folder.

This now works fine with the Form Collections as I originally wanted - I am pretty sure this information is not on the Form Collections page on the website so hope this helps anyone else in future!

Answer (score 1):

you can access the value of the objects inside the `form` you passed to the view using:

```
{% for order in form.orders %}
  {{ order.vars.value.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand

Comment: thanks - I know about that already, should have included in my question sorry, but this does not help me match the correct qty field to the right order item - unless I am missing something?

Comment: So then if you want the `qty` field next to the `id` you can use `{{ order.vars.value.id }} : {{ order.vars.value.qty }}`. Or is the `order` entity more complex than that?

Comment: `{{ order.vars.data.id }}`